# Simple jQuery script fails to do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm new to jQuery and I have a simple jQuery script.

I've put this in my header:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

In my body, I have this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert(1);
    $.getJSON('http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json', function(data) {
      alert(2);
    });
  });
</script>
```

But, while Firebug says the JSON is accessed and there are no errors, I only get the first alert, not the second. Why doesn't the second alert execute?

Answer (score 3):

The json response returned by `http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json` is not valid json, which causes the success handler not to execute.

If you look at the first line the response its `var tumblr_api_read={`, which isn't valid.  To see a valid json example checkout: http://json.org/example.html

This situation is noted in the Jquery Documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the
>   request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,
>   whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

[getJson Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

**Also be sure to close the script tag with an end tag and not the shorthand end tag**

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**If you are accessing this json from outside the providing domain you must indicate its `jsonp`**  This can be accomplished by appending `&callback=?` to the url as described in the jQuery Documentation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(1);
      $.getJSON('http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/SFO?' + 
              'format=application/json&callback=?', function(data){
      alert(2);
    });
  });
```

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/J5jYW/

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json. It should point out any errors.  I added a json example to my answer.

Comment: Ok, here's what I think is valid JSON: http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/SFO?format=application/json ... but even with this URL, the second alert doesn't pop up.

Comment: @user2468491 It didn't post

Comment: I edited it. Apparently you can't use the enter key in comments to get to a next line.

Comment: @user2468491 The json validated

Comment: But I'm still not getting the second alert. ... Could it be possible that this function has been disabled by my host?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look disabled, since Firebug does say the JSON was retrieved. So ... what could possibly be wrong with this?

Comment: Try explicitly closing the script tag with an end tag `</script>` instead of `/>`

Comment: Didn't change anything. I'm going to go try a different host, just because this one has been odd in the past...

Comment: @user2468491 See the notes about jsonp, it worked for me in this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/J5jYW/